# Start activity with provided backstack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications, back-stack

I'd like to start a "precompiled" stack of activities when a user click on a notification. I've tried:

```
Intent[] intents = new Intent[]{
        new Intent(this, ActivityA.class)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK),
        new Intent(this, ActivityB.class)

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0, intents, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

Like [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivities(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent[],%20int)) says, I've added the NEW_TASK flag to the first intent. Anyway when I click on the notification, ActivityB is started and pressing back I've no stack (no ActivityA) and the app is closed.

Comment: Just want to ask your objective in doing the precompiled stack of activities?

Comment: Increase user permanence inside the app. Something like gmail or whatsapp. When you get a notification from a specific user, you enter the detail page, BUT if you tap back you go back to home and don't close the app itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way around.

From Notification -> Redirects to ActivityA like below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context.this,ActivityA.class);
intent.putExtra("isFromNotification",true);
```

On ActivityA -> onCreate method -> after setContentView() method write this lines

```
boolean isFromNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromNotification",false);
    if (isFromNotification){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Note : what this does is it will immediately redirects to ActivityB meanwhile holding the ActivityA on stack. So when user presses back-button it will redirect to ActivityA.

Comment: This was my B plan, but I'd like to avoid this, that seems to be more like a workaround that a proper (read official) solution. Many thanks anyway.